# Jackson doesn't serialize properties of @EmbeddedId property

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm making a Spring app with Hibernate and MySQL. One of my tables has a composite primary key consisting of two foreign keys and a timestamp. I have created the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `trustAssessments` (
  `deviceId` int not null,
  `tmsId` int not null,
  `trustLevel` float not null,
  `honesty` float not null,
  `cooperativeness` float not null,
  `communityInterest` float not null,
  `tstamp` timestamp not null,

  primary key (`tmsId`, `deviceId`, `tstamp`),

  key `FK_PEERTMS_idx` (`tmsId`),

  constraint `FK_PEERTMS` 
  foreign key (`tmsId`) 
  references `peerTMS` (`id`) 

  on delete no action on update no action,

  key `FK_TRUSTED_DEVICE_idx` (`deviceId`),

  constraint `FK_TRUSTED_DEVICE`
  foreign key (`deviceId`) 
  references `device` (`id`)

  on delete no action on update no action

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The corresponding Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trustassessments")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class TrustAssessment {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    //@JsonUnwrapped
    private TrustAssessmentId id;

    @Column(name="trustLevel")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float trustLevel;

    @Column(name="honesty")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float honesty;

    @Column(name="cooperativeness")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float cooperativeness;

    @Column(name="communityInterest")
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private float communityInterest;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="deviceId")
    @MapsId("deviceId")
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    private Device device;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="tmsId")
    @MapsId("tmsId")
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    private PeerTms peerTms;
....
```

And the `TrustAssessmentId` embeddable class which defines the composite key:

```
@Embeddable
public class TrustAssessmentId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="deviceId")
    int deviceId;

    @Column(name="tmsId")
    int tmsId;

    @Column(name="tstamp", updatable=false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date tstamp = new Date();
....
```

I have two problems:

**Problem 1:** The first problem is that, when I use POST to create a new TrustAssessment, it is persisted, but the id value in the json in the response body is empty. I have checked with the debugger that the properties are not null.
For example, if I POST this:

```
{
    "id": {
        "deviceId": 21,
        "tmsId": 20
    },
    "trustLevel": 0.4,
    "honesty": 0.6,
    "cooperativeness": 0.4,
    "communityInterest": 0.2
}
```

I get this in the response body:

```
{
    "id": {},
    "trustLevel": 0.4,
    "honesty": 0.6,
    "cooperativeness": 0.4,
    "communityInterest": 0.2
}
```

I can see in MySQL Workbench that it is persisted:
[image]

**Problem 2:** When I try to do a GET request to retrieve the persisted entity with this request body :

```
{
    "id": {
        "deviceId": 21,
        "tmsId": 20,
        "tstamp": "2019-11-29 19:20:21"
    }
}
```

I get an empty response body, which means it can't find it. This also applies with DEL request which throws:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/tms-rest-again] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to
>   create delete event with null entity] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event
>   with null entity  at
>   org.hibernate.event.spi.DeleteEvent.(DeleteEvent.java:31)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:951)   at
>   com.cybertrust.tms.dao.TrustAssessmentDAOImpl.deleteTrustAssessment(TrustAssessmentDAOImpl.java:58)
>     at
>   com.cybertrust.tms.service.TmsServiceImpl.deleteTrustAssessment(TmsServiceImpl.java:202)
>   ....

Comment: Have you tried to exclude the `tstamp` from the process to see if it causes the problem?

Comment: Abou the GET request, you say that the response you get has an empty id, but are you sure that you dont' retrieve it in the DAO level, have you checked with debug or a sysout?